# How to get a sourcecode from a website and put it through the 'highlight_string'?

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, html-entities

Am getting the source-code of a page but how to get it through the syntax highlighter and then spit it out?

```
<?php 

echo htmlentities( file_get_contents( 'http://www.example.com/post/' ) ); 

highlight_string('http://www.example.com/post/');

?>
```

Comment: highlight_string only colorizes php code not HTML which you're loading from website with file_get_contents. This is helpful http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.highlight-string.php#81257

Comment: You can’t get the source

Answer (score 0):

this function does exactly what you want:
 highlight_file($filename)

php.net/highlight_file